# Changed Guid ID column to int - should I 'clean' anything in SQL Server database to get best performance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have recently changed a site in development from using Guid as Id columns (around 40 tables) to ints - for various reasons including database performance.

The site is only in development - not deployed yet - although there are a few thousand rows in some tables.

I have read about CLEANTABLE but this only appears to be for cleaning used space from variable length columns that have been removed (Guid is not variable length).

I have shrunk the database.

Would re-indexing tables with removed Guids help anything?

Are there any maintenance processes I should do to remove cruft from the database - space used by the Guids - things that may hurt performance - or can I just proceed?

(I can't find anything about column removal and performance on Google - row removal yes).

Comment: I'd assume creating a new PK would automatically generate the index.  I wouldn't assume the index for the former PK isn't still around, but it probably isn't.  Damnit, I just assumed.

Comment: You can't change the datatype of a column from uniqueidentifier to int unless there are no rows in the table. Why did you shrink your database? You are now going to have fragmentation all over the place.

Comment: I say 'changed' - I deleted the old column and re-created it with the new datatype (sometimes I had to transition related tables to new int based PK and FK). I have deleted all Guid columns from the database now. It is a development database - what is wrong with shrinking it then reindexing with, say, 80 fill factor? It's 7MB at this point. I just want to remove cruft. Is there any benefit to doing *anything* or should I just have continued with no attempt to remove cruft?

Comment: (you can't change a column from uniqueidentifier to int - whether there are rows in the table or not FYI).